# Handling hook scripts in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I had a couple of hook scripts for my project for email notification post-commit, and a pre-commit hook to block the empty log messages etc. Keeping this hook scripts, visual svn server not allowing to create the new branches or trunk, any kind of modifications, even creating a new user. when ever feature branch or new project folder to be created, im manually removing the scripts and creating the branches and folder what ever required and recopying the scripts. Is it required to remove every time these scripts in order to do any modifications in the visual svn server.

Answer (score 1):

Upcoming VisualSVN Server 2.5 will bypass execution of Subversion hooks for operation performed from management console:
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00055/